# Преобразовать строку в юзерочитаемую

Tags: python, строки, форматирование

Бэк возвращает строку

```
(1, 'Москва златоглавая', Decimal('280.0000'), 'Ожидание')
```

как преобразовать это например в:

```
Москва златоглавая 280руб Ожидание
```

Comment: строку или, все же, кортеж?

Comment: @Jack_oS Походу кортеж

Comment: почитайте про f-строки, например

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под бэк возвращает? Судя по всему это результат запроса к бд `fetchone()`. Или это апи Вам возвращает текой кортеж? Или сами запрашиваете, пользуетесь ли ORM ? Форматировать текст из кортежа - не сложно, тут скорее надо продумать более удобный ответ.

Comment: Если этот кортеж- просто переданные данные, вытащенные из БД, то что мешает сразу получить от БД нужное представление данных? Т.е. в SELECT выбирать не отдельные поля (включая зачем-то и ненужные), а сразу использовать выражение, которое вернёт нужное представление.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так например:

```
from decimal import Decimal

t = (1, 'Москва златоглавая', Decimal('280.0000'), 'Ожидание')
print(f'{t[1]} {int(t[2])}руб {t[3]}')
```

Вывод:

```
Москва златоглавая 280руб Ожидание
```

Comment: @СергейБогданов Ну это будет `{t[0]}`, можете добавить куда хотите. В вопросе же он нигде не показан.